# How to add text alternative for external images in SVG?

Tags: html, image, svg, d3.js, accessibility

I am adding external images to a d3-generated SVG chart, and would like to have alternative text when external image is not accessible (similar to alt attribute in img element).

But after going through MDN's [SVG Image Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) I don't find similar attribute. Is there a way I can add alternative text to the external image?

Comment: The equivalent would be the `<desc>` child element but I don't think many UAs display it if the image doesn't load. Your only real option would be to code something in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to draw the text before the image, like in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2odwd3ra/1/

```
<text x="350" y="350" font-size="1em" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000">Text remplacement</text>
<image xlink:href="unknown.jpg" x="250" y="250" height="200" width="200" />
```